# Track Down DLL Causing BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net

Our software has a server component which exposes several WCF endpoints.  To give our users a "Training" mode, we create a dynamic DLL which wraps the calls in each of our service interfaces.  This dynamically generated DLL is then loaded into a separate App Domain.  The client app can then switch between "Training" mode and "Normal" mode which affects which endpoint the client uses for communication.

The issue I am having is that I am getting a BadImageFormatException from the dynamically generated DLL running in the child App Domain.  This issue started when I referenced some DLL's made by another team in the company for which I work which indicates to me that it is one of the dependent DLLs which is causing the issue.  I've made sure that every project in both solutions is built using the x86 flag.  Some of the DLL's are .NET 2.0 and some are .NET 4.0 but the application itself runs under the .NET 4.0 CLR (it's set in the App.Config file) so it not have a problem with the .NET 2.0 DLL's.  What I find confusing is that all the referenced assemblies are loaded without issue by the parent executable running in the parent App Domain but as soon as the generated DLL running in the child App Domain tries to load the same assemblies, we get the BadImageFormatException.

I would appreciate any advice as to how to track down exactly which DLL is causing the issue (since Fusion logging doesn't seem to give me any information).  Do I need to set flags to make sure the dynamic DLL and child App Domain are 32-bit and .NET 4?  Any other advice or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone!
Andrew S

Comment: If you are certain that EVERYTHING is x86, are there any dependent DLLs to the one in question, that might be missing. This error will appear instead of DllNotFoundException for dependencies, which makes it quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically generating a DLL try getting away from the `Program Files` folder.  Make a folder on your root drive `C:\` and install your software there.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pabinator.  For testing purposes, I am running the software from my development directory.